# How do I setup cookbooks in git for berkshelf?

Tags: git, chef-infra, berkshelf

We have an internal git server using Gitlab, say, http://git-server.domain.com. I created a "project" group, and pushed a cookbook so, according to git, the cookbook is accessible via http://git-server.domain.com/project/mycookbook.git.

Now I have an environment cookbook called myapp_dev, and its Berksfile looks like this

```
source "https://supermarket.chef.io"
source "http://git-server.domain.com/project"

metadata
```

and its metadata.rb looks like this

```
name             'myapp_dev'
(snip)
version          '0.1.0'

depends          'mycookbook', '~> 1.0.0'
```

When I do a berks install, I get

```
Required artifacts do not exist at the desired version
Missing artifacts: mycookbook
Unable to find a solution for demands: mycookbook(>= 0.0.0), myapp_dev (0.1.0)
```

What do I have configured wrong?

Answer (score 3):

```
source 'https://supermarket.getchef.com'

metadata

cookbook 'my_cookbook', git:'http://git-server.domain.com/project/my_cookbook', tag: 'some_tag'
```

The source is for the community cookbooks, unless you have your own supermarket instance. For the cookbooks that are not on supermarket use the cookbook as shown above in the example.

Comment: I posted this related topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29541656/how-do-i-configure-a-berks-api-server